# c++ using method as parameters to functions

Tags: c++

I don't understand why the following code compile and works:

```
template<typename Predicate> 
void foo(Predicate p) {      
}

bool g(int n) {     
}

void user(int n) { 
    foo(g); 
}
```

`foo` is supposed to get a function object that will run on a data structure but I made the method simpler, because what I don't understand is how can this works? A method isn't an object. The normal way to do it is to create a new class, override `operator()` and then send an instance of that class.

Comment: If this is on gcc/clang, stick a `std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';` in `foo` and see what `p` *really* is. [**See it live**](http://ideone.com/gNQ7Sg).

Comment: A number of the standard library algorithms are dependent on this being possible, e.g. `std::for_each` and `std::copy_if`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, in this case the Predicate parameter is substituted by a function pointer of type `bool (*func) (int)`. Nothing wrong with that...

Answer (score 3):

The `Predicate` template argument can be almost *any* type. So you can use it for function pointers and classes as well as the basic types.

If you use the function argument `p` as a function, then it can be anything that is callable, like a function pointer, an object whose class have an `operator()` member function, a pointer to a static member function, a [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) object, a [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) object or a [lambda expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

It can't be a pointer to a member function though, because to call a pointer to a member function you need an instance to call it on. For this use [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Comment: "Any type" isn't really true. Function parameters may not have function or array type.

Comment: This doesn't answer _why_ it works. Also, `Predicate` is a (type) template argument, so instantiating the template will make `Predicate` a type, not an object.